# how to echo image path? my image cannot display

Tags: php, html

How to echo img src path?

This is my code.

```
echo "<img src = testing/upload/".$r['imagename']."/>";
```

Comment: What is the result of this echo?

Comment: For future reference double quotes (`"`) will look for code, single quotes (`'`) won't. Using single quotes is more efficient when you aren't intentionally outputting code, and will generally output anything as plain text. (From my understanding.)

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '<img src="testing/upload/'.$r['imagename'].'"/>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of **`htmlentities`**

```
$str= "<img src = testing/upload/".$r['imagename']."/>";
echo htmlentities($str);
```

Comment: You're doubly-encoding the `<img ` part, so the result of this code will be `&lt;img src = testing/upload/foo/&gt;`, which is not intended.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
      echo "<img src = \"testing/upload/".$r['imagename']."\"/>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your attribute value isn't enclosed properly, you probably have a character in your image name which breaks the rules for un-enquoted attribute values.

Try this:

```
echo "<img src=\"testing/upload/" . htmlentities( $r['imagename'] ) . "\" />";
```

Answer (score 0):

`echo '<img src="testing/upload/'.$r['imagename'].'/>';`

Use this:)